# what is the use of this patch 'ASOC: dapm: add code to configure dai link parameters from "rpi-3.12.y" '?

Tags: raspbian, linux, archlinux, raspi-config, wolfson-audio-card

Recently i am working on the raspberry pi kernel rpi-3.12.y

When i am using the latest image and modules of it, i am getting an error while

rebooting or halting.

The error message is like unable to handle NULL pointer dereference at location.

Then i debuged and found that the patch **ASOC: dapm: add code to configure dai link
parameters from "rpi-3.12.y"** creating that error, so i removed that patch then everything working fine for me.

I am testing the SPDIF on the wolfson sound card, without having that also it is

working fine.

Then my question is why we need that patch and why it is creating that error when rebooting or halting.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: see this [link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/9/12/121) to know about that. after reading that also i didnt get anything